# Do progressive web apps allow for (non-browser) push notifications or not?

Tags: push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I'm a UI designer doing research on the features of progressive web apps and Flipkart keeps coming up as the gold standard in PWA but I was under the impression that PWA's do not allow for push notifications on iOS or android. But you can clearly see in the following image that these are push notifications from Flipkart:

[Flipkart push notifications on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQdo9.jpg)

Basically, I would like to develop a PWA but the app which allows users to set sleep alarms so I would need to be able to support push notifications to prompt the user to go to sleep - and behave like Flipkart's examples. But all the research I'm finding is not saying clearly whether these push notifications are doable with a PWA.

So have these types of push notifications become doable in PWA's or is this just a native version of the flipkart app? I downloaded it from the app store but it's hard to tell whether it's native or pwa.

Any help or insight would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

I cant speak for Flipkart being a gold standard. They certainly embraced PWA early. Been a while since that point and a lot has happened since then. :)

As for push. Push is supported by all browsers except iPhone and iPad. That is because Apple hates us...just some sarcasm.

I have some articles on push that might help.
https://love2dev.com/pwa/push-notifications/

https://love2dev.com/iphone-push-notifications/

Comment: Thanks for this, these articles were super helpful!

So I guess where I'm getting confused is that I thought Flipkart was a PWA, yet I am getting push notifications on my iPhone from them - see the screenshot below. So, if iOS doesn't support PWA push (browser) notifications, would it be fair to assume that the Flipkart app I downloaded is a native one? Is there anyway to tell between Native and PWA just by looking at it?   

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tj1ylzanblldxv1/IMG_6519.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Since I am not in India I don't really use Flipkart. The site is or was a PWA, I have not checked in a while. If you downloaded flipkart from the app store then it is the native app. If you added to the homescreen from Safari it is a PWA (or to Apple a homescreen app). I think web notifications are supported, which work if you have the site open. They are similar to native push but require the site or at least the browser to be open. I have never used that channel so I am just trying to remember what I know.

Comment: Ok cool - thank you so much Chris, this solves it for me! I really appreciate you taking the time to respond!! Many thanks!